# iphone and exchange: not enough to just reset a terminated user password

Tags: exchange-2010, iphone

It has come to my attention that if I have an Active Directory user with an exchange 2010 account, who has the account setup on an iPhone...  if I reset that user's password, it does not prevent them from sending or receiving emails.

Is this WAD?    I know there is a 'remove pairing' feature in exchange, but I've had limited success with this in the past.

Is there a Best Practices or something for terminating access to email from an iPhone/iPad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a delay when you change the password for an active Sync user as explain in [KB 2612821](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2612821). You might recycle the MSExchangeSyncAppPool pool on the Exchange server as mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2612821) if only one user is affected.

You might also considering to change the "Default Interval for User Tokens in IIS" as explained in [KB 152526](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152526) to a lower value if you need a solution for more user. But this might cause performance issues!

We normally change the password from an user account and then disable the account fully. We also accept the small delay it takes until an account got blocked fully.

According to the "device pairing" the content the pairing is saved in the AD as well. You can use ADUC and use the option VIEW -> "user, Contacts, Groups, and Computers as containers" to show these elements. As far as I know its not recommended by Microsoft, but a customer deletes devices here (instead using the Exchange GUI) which is working for him.